# WebDriver: How can I test that a button is clickable only if there are no invalid values entered?

Tags: validation, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ui-testing

I'm doing some UI automation testing at work and I'm not quite sure how to do this

I have a form that asks for a user's name and date of birth before they can click a button to the next page. If they enter anything with invalid characters (a name of '1111' or a DOB in the future) the input boxes are highlighted in red and an error message appears. How can I test that the 'continue' button is clickable only once valid input is entered?

Comment: It depends on the implementation. Show the HTML code of the button when it is clickable and when it is not.

Comment: IWebElement has several methods available including enabled and displayed.  If the button is being disabled like this: 
    <button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
Then IWebElement will be able to tell you.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, in my project, there are many many "type-of-button".

It can be an input-tage , span-tag  or even image!

So in my opinion, you can't verify that button can be clickable.

You should verify what system does after you click on this button for example: page is loaded, image is uploaded...

Hope it helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

First scenario : 
Username: Valid
Password: Valid

button is displayed

use the driver.FindElement(By.Id("id/xpath of the button ")).Displayed returns true (C# code )
for java there is similar display

else
you enter the invalid scenario

button is not displayed

the above code would give false

Hope this clears your doubt